# iphone apps deploy in device

Tags: iphone

i developed iphone apps in virtual macos on windows.now i want to test my app on real device.

how to deploy application into real device without paying to market.

first i want to test my app is running on device perfectly or not.afterwards i will pay for account.

is there any way.

Thanks in Advance

Aswan

Comment: There is a way to deploy applications on your iPhone, iPod using TestAppFlight. Check my post for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way. To run the app on a device, you need to create a provisioning profile for your app and the devices UDID (unique serial number). You can create these profiles only after joining the (paid) developer program.

Comment: There is a way to deploy applications on your iPhone, iPod using TestAppFlight. Check my post for details.

Answer (score 2):

While the simulator should give you a good idea, the only option for testing on the device without paying is jail-breaking the device (and possibly voiding your warranty if the device breaks while jail-broken).

Answer (score 1):

Here is tutorial on [How to build iOS application using Windows and OpenSSL](http://tinyurl.com/cfgnz55) and deploy it on your device(iPad, iPhone). You just need an Apple developer account.