# How can i transfer my coded and compiled "hello world" iphone app on Iphone ?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App Minus App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store)
>   [iphone apps deploy in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634567/iphone-apps-deploy-in-device)

am a newbie. I have coded and compiled a simple hello world app. I am wondering what file now needs to be transferred to iphone ? And how ? Is it possible to run it on my personal iphone, without submitting it to "Appstore" in between.

thanks

Comment: Check out my answer here: [iPhone App Minus App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423913/427309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test apps on your iPhone you have to be a member of the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), which costs $99 per year.

In that case, you can use Xcode to deploy to the device. Right click on your iPhone on the **Organizer** and select **Add Device to Provisioning Profile**.

Then you can select your device and run your app on it.

[image]

Comment: Just note that this is not the only way to deploy to a device, you can use a jailbreak as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Buy the iOS developer license here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/
- Go to the iOS provisioning portal: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action and follow the assistant to create dev certificate, register your iPhone, and get the provisioning profile
- After you finish all the steps above, you'll see a new selection in your XCode (your phone name) where you can run your app on.